# Options for @findAll in protractor

Tags: selenium, javascript, protractor

I want to use two identifiers for the same element and use the first one found.
With Java, we have `@findAll.`
Is there any way to that with javascript protractor?

Any function/options or something relative?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no decorators in JavaScript.

What you can do is to locate multiple elements and then use [`.first()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first):

```
var MyPageObject = function () {
    this.multipleElement = element.all(by.css(".someclass"));
    this.firstElement = this.multipleElements.first();
}
```

This way, you are not repeating locators and following the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

finally I did this easy function:

```
function locateElement(desktopLocator, mobileLocator)
{
    var locator = "";
    if(browser.platform === "Desktop") 
    {
        return desktopLocator;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return mobileLocator;
    }
}

myProfileTab: locateElement(element(by.tagName('element1')), element(by.tagName('element2')))
```

It Works perfectly now.